Google colabs says index out of bound while local machine says otherwise
I've been trying to use google colabs tensorflow to compile a project of mine. It has no issue compiling with lower samples on my local machine (1000 and such) but takes too long when compiling all of the instances (42000).
def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
    for row in dataset:
        value = row[column]
        if isinstance(value, str):  # Check if the value is a string
            value = value.strip()
            if not value.replace('.', '').isdigit():  # Check if the value is not numeric
                continue
        try:
            row[column] = float(value)
        except (ValueError, AttributeError):
            pass  # Skip conversion for non-numeric values

and this is the function call
filename = 'Train_data.csv'
dataset = load_csv(filename)
dataset = dataset[1:]
  for i in range(0, len(dataset[0]) - 1):
          str_column_to_float(dataset, i)

I haven't found any issue and can't see why this only happens in colabs and runs fine on vscode I've even tried to specify the columns that have the literal words in them but to no avail
`
def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())

for i in range(0, len(dataset[0])-1):
    if i not in [1, 2, 3, 42]:  # Skip conversion for columns 1, 2, 3, and 42
        str_column_to_float(dataset, i)


Assuming you're using Pandas or a similar library, you can probably avoid a lot of pain by directly coercing by-columns with the builtin vector operations, which will be hundreds of times faster than python loop iteration!
filename = 'Train_data.csv'
dataset = load_csv(filename)
#dataset = dataset[1:]  # is this needed?

for column in dataset.columns:
    dataset[column] = dataset[column].astype(float, errors="ignore")

Note this can result in mixed data in columns, which is what would originally happen, but may be impossible or is undesirable for your dataset
If you're just not sure which entire columns are non-numeric, while some string columns could be floats instead just check for any NaNs and skip those
    ...
    s_tmp = pd.to_numeric(dataset[column], errors="coerce")
    if any(s_tmp.isna()):    # at least one value is NaN (non-float)
        continue             # ignore column
    # opportunity to coerce or assert type again
    dataset[column] = s_tmp  # clobber column with new

Finally, you may find you can completely save and load the data in a nicer way as described here Changing strings to floats in an imported .csv
more on pandas.to_numeric here Answer to Converting strings to floats in a DataFrame
